# Regex asterisk is not working in specified manner

Tags: regex

the following regular expression disallows other than numbers and periods. `[^\d+\.?\d*]` 
but test string we give `12** asd`  it result wrong it matches `12**`.

how does it match asterisk.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code...

Answer (score 1):

> the following regular expression disallows other than numbers and
>   periods.[^\d+.?\d*]

No, it doesn't do what you want.

> it result wrong it matches 12**

I can't reproduce that. In-fact it matched a string except `12**`

Here is the explanation from [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/jK1rR7). Putting all together don't make much sense.

```
/[^\d+.?\d*]/
Negated char class [^\d+.?\d*] matches any character except:
   \d Digit [0-9]
   +.? One of the following characters +.?
   \d Digit [0-9]
   * The character *
```

**Note :** `*`, `?` and `+` don't have their special meaning inside `[]` and all of them are treated as literal character

---

Probably you are looking for

```
[0-9.]+
```

Comment: I still don't get why the OP's regex matched a `*`

Comment: @PeterAlfvin It doesn't match, at-least for me. check [here](http://regex101.com/r/jK1rR7). Please check my updated ans.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't match. I was just trying to explain what the OP reported. +1